# DNN - How to add a new view in my module?

Tags: view, module, dotnetnuke

What i did is copy my view page and changed it's name to example(succes) and i added the module definitions in host > extensions > edit. The page loads but it doesn't load my content. When i add a breakpoint to the page_load it doesn't get called.

Any ideas?

I'm using the latest version of dotnetnuke.

Succes.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Succes.ascx.cs" Inherits="FortyFingers.EventsEnrollment.Succes" %>


 This is my succes page!
```

Succes.ascx.cs:

```
namespace --
{
    public partial class Succes : PortalModuleBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

            }
            catch (Exception exc) //Module failed to load
            {
                Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(this, exc);
            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Add user to event - click event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should update your post with the code you are using to build the URL in DNN.

Comment: It's probably still loading your View.ascx.  You either need to change this page to be your default View page, or set up something in your View.ascx to goto the new page.  Not quite sure what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong url, i had to use the module id as well to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the module definition, you need to add the 'View' control to your definition. Also, modify your manifest file to add the new 'view' control. Delete the module from your page, recompile in 'Release' mode and re-add it.

Answer (score 0):

Does your success page have extensive logic?

If not, consider simply changing the visibility of your table and alerts from the code behind after the form is successfully submitted.

For example:

```
<asp:panel runat="server" id="SuccessAlert" visible="false">
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        You're message has been sent.  
    </div>
</asp:panel>

<asp:panel runat="server" id="ExampleForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="FirstName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" maxlength="255" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">    
        <label for="LastName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" maxlength="255" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="EmailAddress" class="sr-only">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" maxlength="255" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="SubmitButton">Send</button>
</asp:panel>
```

And then from your code behind--after successful--operation simply call:

```
ExampleForm.Visible = false;
SuccessAlert.Visible = true;
```